# Rails undefined method "to_time_preserves_timezone"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Something was broken and now no one generator is not works but i'm nothing change after i'm using rails generator last time. That's i got in a console

```
/home/sanua/ct/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:15:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
 from /home/sanua/ct/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'/home/sanua/ct/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:15:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
 from /home/sanua/ct/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I constantly see this message whatever i write(rails generate controller, model...)

Comment: comment line number 15 in initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb and try again

Comment: So your rails works now?

Comment: No, same error.

Comment: I don't think it will be the same error, Do you mind showing what's in new_framework_defaults.rb

Comment: Add your `new_framework_defaults.rb` file to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to delete the `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` after that, as the correct version will then be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

@TRIGUN117 I would suggest you to create a new rails app since its a problem with initializer. I believe something is corrupted in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just have an incompatible version of `active_support`. If you do not belong on gem versions, simply delete `Gemfile.lock` and execute `bundle` to update gems and regenerate the `Gemfile.lock`. If you do, or problem still exists, look through `Gemfile` and make sure that all rails' gems have the same version specified.